# PF: Block all, but one subnet firewall rule?

Tags: freebsd, filter, block, pf, packet

I'm trying to do something that I thought would be relatively simple: Block all the traffic to a test server, other than my company's subnet.

I've tried things along these lines (111.111.0.0 is my placeholder for this example), but only the block seems to work:

```
block in all
pass in from 111.111.0.0
pass in on en0 from 111.111.0.0
pass in all from 111.111.0.0
```

None of those pass in lines seem to work (I know some of those might throw a syntax error, as I'm just grabbing all the lines I've commented out while testing).

Is this less simple than I assumed?  Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

its because its specifying a single ip, you need to write it with the subnet:

```
pass in from 111.111.0.0/16
```

`man pf.conf` should list a few methods of defining ranges and blocks. *A side note, take care to ensure there are no `drop quick` kind of rules **above** your `pass`, and no rules **below** that could accidently match and block your packets.*

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check the range of IPs on behalf of the subnet then please use the following IP calculator link.

https://www.calculator.net/ip-subnet-calculator.html?cclass=any&csubnet=24&cip=111.90.100.200&ctype=ipv4&printit=0&x=90&y=14

For example, if your IP is **111.90.100.200** and you want the range from **111.90.100.1 - 111.90.100.254** then you need to write your IP like this **111.90.100.0/24** or **111.90.100.200/24**.

For further ranges please use the link to the IP calculator.